# it is possible to pick kivy ids using loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, kivy

Hello can i pick multiple kivy ids using loop?Lets say i have 3 ids(one,two,three) 
i picking ids from database like c is id of kivy widgets.

```
kvids=0
while kvids < 3
    c=select 'kivy id'#pseudocode
    self.ids.c.text='not work'
```

Is ever possible to use something like this? Or is there any another simple solution for something like this. i need to pick some information from database and bind it to widgets. I have no idea about this. 
kv:

```
Button:
    id:one
Button:
    id:two
Button:
    id:three
```

I didnt paste all code because i just need solution no matter how looks code.

Comment: It is possible. Please refer to my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. Please refer to the example below for details.

When your kv file is parsed, kivy collects all the widgets tagged with id’s and places them in this self.ids dictionary type property. That means you can also iterate over these widgets and access them dictionary style:

```
for key, val in self.ids.items():
    print("key={0}, val={1}".format(key, val))
```

or

```
self.ids['one'].text = "Button 1"
```

or

```
self.ids.two.text = 'Button 2'
```

## Example

### main.py

```
import sqlite3

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class DemoKivyIDsDB(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DemoKivyIDsDB, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.set_widgets_text()

    def set_widgets_text(self):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("kivy.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        cursor.execute("SELECT widget_id FROM kivyids")
        print("fetchall:")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        for r in result:
            print(r)
            self.ids[r[0]].text = "not work"


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return DemoKivyIDsDB()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<DemoKivyIDsDB>:
    Button:
        id: one
    Button:
        id: two
    Button:
        id: three
```

### KivyIDsDB.py

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("kivy.db")

cursor = connection.cursor()

# delete
# cursor.execute("""DROP TABLE kivyids;""")

sql_command = """
CREATE TABLE kivyids (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
widget_id VARCHAR(20),
widget_text VARCHAR(30));
"""

# create table
cursor.execute(sql_command)

sql_command = """
INSERT INTO kivyids (id, widget_id, widget_text)
VALUES (NULL, 'one', 'Button 1');
"""

cursor.execute(sql_command)

sql_command = """
INSERT INTO kivyids (id, widget_id, widget_text)
VALUES (NULL, 'two', 'Button 2');
"""

cursor.execute(sql_command)

sql_command = """
INSERT INTO kivyids (id, widget_id, widget_text)
VALUES (NULL, 'three', 'Button 3');
"""

cursor.execute(sql_command)

connection.commit()

connection.close()
```

### Output

[image]